# Test Google Analytics GA Cookie Parser without going through AdWords link?

Tags: parsing, cookies, google-ads-api

I'm using this Google Analytics cookie parser https://github.com/joaolcorreia/Google-Analytics-PHP-cookie-parser

Is there anyway I can get cookied through our PPC campaign so I can test parsing the campaign name term etc without being charged?

Campaign name and medium come up as a referral site right now which is correct, just wondering if I can test my ad get cookied without being charged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can test this is by clicking on an actual ad and paying for it :-(

You can use the "Ad Preview" Tool, but its only a preview tool and cookies will not be deployed on your browser.

My suggestions is you check your adwords for the lowest CPC keywords, which is usually your brand name. Use that keyword and then click on it. If you are not bidding on your brand name (company name), then create a sample campaign with a couple of brand keywords, then choose the cheapest CPC one!

If you just want to check what the cookie looks like, etc.. Then click on your competitors keywords and cookies will be dropped. They will pay for your testing, but I don't think this is what you are looking for.

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks I figured there was no other way than to click the actual ad to get cookied.